# Textfield display issues in some versions of Flash Player

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-cs5, textfield, flashplayer-10

I was just wondering if anyone else has come across some strange textfield display issues in any of the recent Flash Player releases. Both IE and FF were having display problems, both in slightly different ways. FF would simply display the text as if it were a single line field, no wordwrap, whereas IE would display the text vertically, Chinese style. These are classic dynamic text fields, compiled in CS5 by the way.

The issue seems to occur when you assign text to a field when its x coordinate is off the stage, then move it onto the stage after this. I so far haven't found anyone else mentioning this problem on the interwebs, which I find strange, as it is a pretty bizarre one! Incidentally, the same thing was happening with the textfields on a workmate's AIR application.

These problems for me were occurring in FP 10.3.183.5 in IE, and FP 10.3.183.7 in FF. I updated FF's player to the latest (10.3.183.10) and the problem appears to be resolved. Hopefully this is the end of it, but it's just a little disconcerting, as you never know what version your clients will be using!

I'm not able to post images here yet, but I've included links to screenshots of the problem occuring in IE, and also it displaying properly in the latest player in FF. I've left a border on the textfield to show you it's dimensions.

Any insights (or simply someone else saying they have also come across this issue so I don't feel alone haha) would be much appreciated,
Cheers.

-> [problem in 10.3.183.5](http://i1096.photobucket.com/albums/g338/el_mateo/IE1031835flashplayerscreenshot-1.jpg)

-> [no problem in 10.3.183.10](http://i1096.photobucket.com/albums/g338/el_mateo/FF10318310flashplayerscreenshot-1.jpg)

edit: <strike>Here's a link</strike> (don't have enough rep to post more links yet) Here is the URL to a dummy swf that has the problem: mattlukins[dot]com[dot]au/misc/dumb_textfield_thing.zip

(screenshot: i1096[dot]photobucket[dot]com/albums/g338/el_mateo/IE-flash-103183_dummy_screenshot.jpg). I've since updated my FP version in IE to the latest, and sure enough it's ok now, but if anyone is still running 10.3.183.5 then you might be able to see the bug still.

Comment: Weird. I'll try to reproduce. You should probably file a bug report to adobe

Comment: Thanks for that. Yeah, I probably should. It's quite a bad problem to happen so you would think they'd be interested to know!

Comment: Did you try to trace out the textfield width in each example? Also, can you produce a dummy swf that has the same problem? I'd be happy to download and take a look.

Comment: Yeah I did all sorts of traces til I was blue in the face :) I could see it change from it's original width the the final one, but nowhere in the code was there anything telling it to. It was just perplexing!

I've added a link to a dummy fla&swf that has the field receiving text whilst off stage (ie the x coord in the negatives) then being placed on after. The problem was happening in flashplayer 10.3.183.5 for IE, and I've provided a screenshot as evidence, but I'm not sure of the chances of replicating it if you have a different FP version.

Comment: I've updated my IE's player, so I can't even replicate it myself anymore haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug that has been fixed in the latest version of Flash. See https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2941694

Also another question about it: [Workaround for TextField bug in FP 10.3.183.5 and 10.3.183.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591171/workaround-for-textfield-bug-in-fp-10-3-183-5-and-10-3-183-7/7598734#7598734)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you Laurent. I feel better knowing it was a known bug that has recently been addressed. I should have searched on this site more thoroughly before posing the question heh. Thanks again!